# Circular dependency on nested concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Any got any idea why, on my production server I can't use nested concerns in model?

I have a model `Landing`

```
class Landing < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Claimable

end
```

and concern

```
module Claimable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

end
```

Everything is working fine, but Claimable is stricly Landing logic so I would like to put it a nested route

```
class Landing < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Landing::Claimable

end
```

and

```
 module Landing::Claimable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

end
```

This is working on my developement machine (OSX Yosemite), but when I deploy to a Linux production server I receive error:

```
/home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant': Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Landing::Claimable (RuntimeError)
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/app/models/landing.rb:20:in `<class:Landing>'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/app/models/landing.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/app/models/concerns/landing/claimable.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /home/app/app/current/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/app/app/current/config.ru:3:in `require'
from /home/app/app/current/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /home/app/app/current/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /home/app/app/current/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:42:in `for'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:170:in `load_adapter'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:74:in `start'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/runner.rb:200:in `run_command'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/runner.rb:156:in `run!'
from /home/app/app/releases/a34cd4a786d8f6c35179fb8eebc34469f471192a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.3/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/app/app/releases/68f6492bb01f28373b95f26f34b609fdb99dc9cd/vendor/bundle/bin/thin:16:in `load'
from /home/app/app/releases/68f6492bb01f28373b95f26f34b609fdb99dc9cd/vendor/bundle/bin/thin:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: u have a class Landing and module Landing, don't u think is too much?

Comment: remove `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` from `Landing::Claimable`

Comment: @CodeGroover as far as In understand, that's how namespacing works with concerns. paritosh-piplewar Still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually has to do with your `config.eager_load` settings on your application. You have a different setting in the production environment from the development one, which is perfectly normal and the intended use, but that's why you experience different behaviors from development to production.

As a possible solution, I suggest you avoid using the one-line namespaced class definition and change it to multiple lines instead.

Try changing:

```
module Landing::Claimable
end
```

to:

```
module Landing
  module Claimable
  end
end
```

Comment: hey @Michal, don't forget about the bounty ;)

Comment: I was sure, I awared you with it, sorry :)

Comment: This will break on you again in 4.2.1. You will get an error that says "Landing is not a class".

Comment: @AKWF oh crap. Not there yet, I can't try. Any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317204/rails-4-2-will-not-recognize-my-model-concerns/30326477#30326477