# How do I fix the error "Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant" on Heroku / Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport-concern

I'm getting this error on Heroku after I deploy, but I'm not getting the error or experiencing problems with this locally.

What is wrong with the following naming / namespacing, etc? What am I missing?

models/concerns/purchase/finalize_utils.rb

```ruby
module Purchase::FinalizeUtils
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
end
```

models/purchase.rb

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base 
  include FinalizeUtils
end
```

log error:

```
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553902+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Purchase::FinalizeUtils
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553903+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553903+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553904+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/app/models/purchase.rb:19:in `<class:Purchase>'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553904+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/app/models/purchase.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553905+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553906+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553906+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553907+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553907+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553907+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553908+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553909+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/app/models/concerns/purchase/finalize_utils.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553909+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553909+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553910+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553910+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553910+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553911+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553912+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553911+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553912+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553912+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553913+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553913+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553914+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553914+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553914+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553915+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553915+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553915+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553916+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553916+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553917+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553917+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553917+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553918+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553918+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553918+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553919+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553921+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553921+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2017-01-26T22:39:25.553922+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/config/environment.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682451/circular-dependency-on-nested-concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what's it's worth for future people with this problem, I discovered that my problem was a combination of things.

For one, the reason this was functioning differently if production and development was this setting:

```
config.eager_load
```

The reason it wasn't wasn't failing for similar "setups" (i.e. User::MyModule) seems to have something to do with the order in which files are processed for eager_loading.

The problem was that the concern was seeming to get loaded before the model sometimes, and sometimes the other way around. Both versions have problems, since the Class Purchase wasn't seen as the same class (since one was a subclass and one wasn't) and wasn't reopened properly.

So I needed to change this:

```
module Purchase::FinalizeUtils
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
end
```

to this:

```
#models/concerns/purchase/finalize_utils.rb 
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base  
  module FinalizeUtils
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    end
  end
end
```

This allowed the class Purchase to be reopened instead of redefined. Or something like that. Either way the above method allows me to namespace my concerns for including like this:

```
#models/purchase.rb
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base 
  include FinalizeUtils
end
```

The file isn't named to be found by lazy loading, but since the module is in the class, the lookup path finds it.